# How to use gulp to organize the different js file in different html?

Tags: gulp, organized

How to use gulp to organize the different js file in different html?
is the only way I can do is to define each page to gulp task ? Or gulp have a better way can detect file automatically?

This is my situation below.
I have two html 'index.html','content.html'

- `index.html` need `plugin_A.js`
- `content.html` need `plugin_B.js`

And my gulp file:

```
gulp.task('index_concat', function() {
    return gulp.src('./app/js/plugin_A.js')
        .pipe(concat('index.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js/'));
});
gulp.task('content_concat', function() {
    return gulp.src('./app/js/plugin_B.js')
        .pipe(concat('content.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js/'));
});
```

If I had 100 pages, the tasks were too big!!!
I think this is a stupid way to define each page, but I have no idea how to get better. Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some name convention for your plugins like pluginName_index.js and pluginName_content.js . So you be able to do something like that:

```
function yourFunction(pluginName,targetName){
   return gulp.src('./app/js/'+pluginName)
      .pipe(concat(targetName))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js/'));
}

fs.readdirSync('.app/js/pluginFolder')
.filter(function(fileName) {
    var fileNameParts = fileName.split('_');
    yourFunction(fileName,fileNameParts[1]);
});
```